# SciFi movie where woman has alien baby

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

It was an old American movie where a doctor believes his wife has an alien baby growing inside her belly, and in the end he insists on doing surgery on her (by opening her torso) to find this alien baby. The scene is very depressing and in the end the woman dies, but it remains unclear if there actually was an alien or he was just obsessed with the idea.

I think I saw this in the late 90's. It was an older movie — could even have been in black and white.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you see this and when do you think it was from?

Comment: I think I saw this in the late 90's, it was an older movie - could even have been in black and white.

Answer (score 17):

[Progeny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progeny_(film)) (1998)? Wikipedia gives a basic plot summary:

> Sherry Craig, a professional woman, happily discovers she is pregnant. While this is happy news for her and her husband Craig who is a doctor, both begin having strange memories from the night of conception. Uneasiness then becomes terror when both are convinced that she is carrying something alien inside her body. Sherry's therapist Dr. Susan Lamarche believes that Sherry has a psychological problem, for which Craig is to blame.

According to [Inverse](https://www.inverse.com/culture/progeny-25-year-anniversary), the doctor kills his wife in the end by accident trying to get the allegedly alien baby out of her:

> If it’s a straightforward alien abduction tale, then Craig’s fears have been validated, but he’s lost the love of his life, been convicted as a spousal killer, and is now left holding a mutant spawn. If it was all in his mind, then we’ve been watching a man slowly descend into madness.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be - but watching the trailer it's not what I was watching. In the movie you never see the baby, or an alien. It is far more subtle, and the most terrifying scene is in the end when the husband opens his wife's torso, leaving her wide open to die - as he is desparately looking for the alien fetus.

Comment: "Sherry Craig" ... "her husband Craig" ... So his name is Craig Craig?!

Comment: @JohnGordon omg lol

Comment: @JohnGordon only if she changed her name

Answer (score 0):

This might be "The Stranger Within", a 1974 made-for-television movie based on Richard Matheson's novella "Trespass". I've included a link to the film's Wikipedia entry.

There is also a 1990 film with the same title, but that film is a thriller with no sci-fi or fantasy elements

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjN8PmykcGCAxWZlYkEHf8EA4AQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FThe_Stranger_Within&usg=AOvVaw2iWtq75Tp5i4eaUEplfRaJ&opi=89978449

[image]

Comment: Does this match the plot beyond what's described in the question title? It doesn't seem like the husband is a doctor, no surgery happens, and the woman is abducted by aliens instead of dying in the end.

Comment: I never realized Barbara Eden had more than one role!

Comment: @MarkRansom your life will not be complete without *Harper Valley PTA*.